# Count number of consecutive spaces in Series

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a Series like:

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series([
    'the quick brown fox',
    'the  quick pink fox',
    'a quick brown   fox',
    'the jumpy  brown fox    ',
    'the quick  brown animal',
])
```

I would like to count the number of consecutive spaces in each element. So my expected output is:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    2
dtype: int64
```

because the first row contains only one consecutive space, the second one contains two consecutive spaces (between `the` and `quick`), the third row contains three consecutive spaces (between `brown` and `fox`), and so on...

I know of `ser.str.count(' ')`, but that'll give me the total number of spaces, even if they're not consecutive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract all consecutive spaces with a regex (using [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html)), then get the lengths with [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and find the maximum length per initial row with [`GroupBy.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
(ser
 .str.extractall('(\s+)')[0]
 .str.len()
 .groupby(level=0).max()
 .reindex(ser.index, fill_value=0) # optional (see below)
)
```

*NB. If there is a possibility that you have strings without space and you would like to get 0, you need to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html).*

output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

[findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html?pandas.Series.str.findall) gets you a list of spaces strings, just take the length of the longest string per list:

```
ser.str.findall(' +').apply(lambda s: max(map(len, s)) if s else 0)
```

Result:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    2
dtype: int64
```